# CSS "transform: rotate()" affecting overall design with "position: absolute" (not aligning properly)

Tags: css, rotation, transform, css-position, rotatetransform

I fear I quite don't know how to explain it as well as I can show it. So I've set up **[this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bj7q7/)**

As you can see, the nav menu is not where it should be. It should be set exactly at the bottom border of the head element and to the left border. I.e. `bottom: 0` and `left: 0`. However, I'm setting a rotation of -90degs and it is obvious that the absolute positioning on the `nav` element is happening before the rotation or perhaps rather on the original element as if the rotation didn't exist.

I've tried using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to try and see if I could solve it that way. But I can't quite get the grasp of these pseudo-elements. In both cases, the rotation was bypassed. (Without the rotation, the `nav` element obviously positions itself where it should be.)

This is basically the code:

```
<div id="head">
    <div id="title">My Web</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something Else</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Nothing fancy.

And this is the CSS (the parts of it that matter to this issue):

```
#head {
    position: relative;
}
nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 9px;
}
```

How it's working: **[you can see this in the Fiddle project.](http://jsfiddle.net/bj7q7/)**

Hope someone out there can give me a hand.

---

**P.S**. Also, sometimes, and depending on the size of the text inside the `<a>` tags, it seems, the distance between the vertical elements in the `nav` is *slightly* increased, as if in half a pixel, meaning the borders become fuzzy. **[You can see this in this other version](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbVKH/)** with just 4 more characters and a space in one of the `<a>` elements. Can't understand why this would make a difference. However, it makes the menu look rather bad when it happens!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because the `nav` element has different width and height. By default an element is rotated by its centre, so in case of your `nav` the corners of this block after rotation don't match. The solution to this problem is to set the `transform-orgin` property that will move the rotation point so that the bottom left corners before and after transformation are in the same place. In your case it's `transform-origin: 75px 75px;` (works independently of the `<a>` length).

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj7q7/7/)

Unfortunately it won't solve the problem for IE8- as those browsers doesn't support transformation and use their own way of rotating things.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mateusz! Good tip to know.

Comment: By the way, this also solves the issue in my *P.S.*. The gap was due to distortion from the rotation. I thought it was inevitable and was about to choose clarity over the effect, but by setting the `transform-origin` away from the center (`50% 50%`) I was able to avoid this distortion. In fact, I believe I can generalize that rotation looks better on an element (an overall is less of a hassle) as close to a corner as you can set it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the padding of the ul in your nav. Try to fine-tune

nav ul { padding-left: 0; }

(Chrome's dev-tools might help you to find the missing last 1 or 2 pixels, helped me to find the ul padding.)

Comment: Hi, Dennis. Thanks for the answer. However, working with the `ul` padding is doing nothing for me. Did it change anything for you in the Fiddle?

Comment: Hi QuestionerNo27. Sorry, just tested it with Chrome and Firefox, they both act like expected. Maybe this post can help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215784/css-3-text-rotation-bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215784/css-3-text-rotation-bug) Your offset is 13px in your example.

Comment: So here's a very nice overview (I think) to the animation stuff in CSS3: [http://www.css3files.com/transform/](http://www.css3files.com/transform/). Considering the fact that your rotation takes place after the placement it becomes clear why your nav goes over the "top" (bottom ;)) I'm afraid you'll have to fix it by setting an appropriate bottom-offset. Sorry I couldn't help better.

Comment: Not at all, @Dennis, thanks a lot for your time! And thanks for the ref. I'll definitely give it a good read.