# CSS: rotate image and align top left

Tags: css, image, layout, alignment, rotatetransform

I am trying to rotate an image using a `CSS` transform such that it stays correctly aligned within the surrounding `div`, i.e. the top left corner of the image should be aligned with the top left corner of the `div`.

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbpLC/1/) (-> click on `[rotate]`) this does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

(Note that I'd be using this in an online image viewer so I cannot hardcode an offset for the rotated image. There's a lot of similar questions but I haven't found this exact question.)

Comment: did you use 'overflow:hidden' property to your div..?

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` would only cut away parts of the image, but not correct the alignment.

Answer (score 44):

If you want it to be done in CSS, this is the way:

```
.rot90 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Firefox 3.6 Firefox 4 */
    /*-moz-transform-origin: right top; */
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* IE9 */
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg); /* W3C */  
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

## [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/mbpLC/19/)

The trick is to rotate the image around the left bottom corner. Once done, it is down by 100% of the height; translate it and now it is ok.

To get the same effect for the inverse rotation: (hover to transform)

```css
div:hover #myimage {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); /* Safari */
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox 3.6 Firefox 4 */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); /* IE9 */
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); /* W3C */  
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -ms-transform-origin: top right;
    -o-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <img id="myimage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/mediawiki/a/a9/Example.jpg" style="border: 3px solid silver;" />
</div>
```

Comment: How about rotating -90 degrees? What other values need changing, and to what?

Comment: @MrPablo added snippet for the inverse rotation

Answer (score 4):

Using some jQuery, you can get the `offset` of the parent, subtract that from the new rotated `offset` and use margin to put it back to the container. It works with all rotations. Here is [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pEG3b/2/).

JS:

```
function rotate(elm, deg) {
    var offsetContLeft, offsetContTop, offsetLeft, offsetTop, newLeft, newTop;
    $(elm).css('transform', 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    // Get the container offset
    offsetContLeft = $(elm).parent().offset().left;
    offsetContTop= $(elm).parent().offset().top;
    // get the new rotated offset
    offsetLeft = $(elm).offset().left;
    offsetTop = $(elm).offset().top;
    // Subtract the two offsets.
    newLeft = offsetContLeft - offsetLeft;
    newTop = offsetContTop - offsetTop;
    // Apply the new offsets to the margin of the element.
    $(elm).css('margin-left', newLeft).css('margin-top', newTop);
}

$("#myrotate").click(function (e) { 
      // pass in the element to rotate and the desired rotation.
      rotate('#myimage', 90);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From the answers given thus far I take it that there is no simpler approach than using JavaScript to "realign" the image. Let me therefore share the approach which I ended up using:

```
var step = 0;

$("#myrotate").click(
  function (e) { 
    step += 1;
    var img = $("#myimage");
    img.css('transform', 'rotate('+ step*90 +'deg)'); // could be extended to work also in older browsers
    var d = img.width() - img.height();
    img.css('margin-left', -d/2*(step%2));
    img.css('margin-top',   d/2*(step%2));
  }
);
```

`myrotate` is the `id` of the `<a>` which I abuse as switch, `myimage` is (guess) the `id` of the `img` to rotate.

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbpLC/18/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a simplier way, but you can set margin of the image after rotation like this.

```
margin:68px -66px;
```

You can use js to get image width and height so it sets values accordingly to the size of image. I used manual way.

http://jsfiddle.net/YQktn/3/

EDIT:

You can always mess with

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-moz-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-ms-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-o-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
transform-origin: 75px 75px;
```

as found here: [CSS "transform: rotate()" affecting overall design with "position: absolute" (not aligning properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121058/css-transform-rotate-affecting-overall-design-with-position-absolute-no)

Answer (score 0):

I take the @Lost Left Stack example and changed it to work with all rotations, and be repetitive.
Resets margins for repetitive rotations.
Also set right and bottom margins.

```
function rotateImage(elm, deg) {
    $(elm).css('margin-left', 0).css('margin-top', 0);
    $(elm).css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    // Get the container offset
    var offsetContLeft = $(elm).parent().offset().left;
    var offsetContTop = $(elm).parent().offset().top;
    // get the new rotated offset
    var offsetLeft = $(elm).offset().left;
    var offsetTop = $(elm).offset().top;
    // Subtract the two offsets.
    var newOffsetX = Math.floor(offsetContLeft - offsetLeft) + 1;
    var newOffsetY = Math.floor(offsetContTop - offsetTop) + 1;
    $("#a").text(newOffsetX + "-" + newOffsetY)
    // Apply the new offsets to the margin of the element.
      $(elm).css('margin-left', newOffsetX).css('margin-top', newOffsetY)
          .css('margin-right', newOffsetX).css('margin-bottom', newOffsetY);
}
var rot = 0;
$("#myrotate").click(function (e) { 
rot += 15;
      rotateImage('#myimage', rot);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v4qa0x5g/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue I've worked on today, and top comment did help a lot to get started.

How ever,

In my scenario I'm uploading pictures that will be added to generated pdf upon export.
I do allow users to rotate them in front end, and save the values of rotation (i.e. 0, 90, 180, 270) with the picture it self.

.ctp file used for generation of the file contained something along the lines of

`echo '<img class="image" src="'.h($imageSrcPath).'" alt="" />';`

So to rotate I've created classes as following:

```
img.rotate_0 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}

img.rotate_270 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
}

img.rotate_180 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}

img.rotate_90 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
}
```

and changed .ctp file to

`echo '<img class="rotate_'.h($rotation).'" src="' . h($imageSrcPath) . '" alt="" style="margin-top:15px;")/>';`

Seeing as different degrees of rotation need me to have ever so slightly different `transform-origin`