# CSS position absolute stops the rotate property

Tags: html, css, rotation, position, absolute

I'm new to html/css/php, so it may be a dumb question, but I've searched the documentation of position: absolute and transform: rotate and I don't see any hint of why the "absoluteness" turns off rotation.

I'm trying to do this on https://wojtek.denisdev.pl and when I remove "position: absolute" part of "style", then the boar rotates. I've seen that people join both (like here: [CSS "transform: rotate()" affecting overall design with "position: absolute" (not aligning properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121058/css-transform-rotate-affecting-overall-design-with-position-absolute-no)), but it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the link here https://wojtek.denisdev.pl i can see only one error from your css file that causes that error and here it is `;`

so your resulting css for the boar.png was

```
transform: rotate(
45deg) position: absolute;
```

which was missing the the closing css tag `;`

for it to work, copy and replace this code with the above code in the boar.png line completely

```
<img src="boar.png" id="1" style="transform: rotate(45deg);position: absolute;">
```

Comment: I've done it, thanks!